# How can store ftp's username and password in android with securely way

Tags: java, android

In my class, I have ftp's username and password there is problem, if someone open and reverse .apk, it will be seen my ftp's information. How can I store and keep and secure my information in android?

Comment: Use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to protect your APK

Comment: this ll be full protection for my project ?

Comment: Read full documentation of proGuard all detail given

Comment: There's no reliable way to keep data secret from someone if you put it on their device, and if you're using plain FTP, you might as well just assume the password will be sniffed anyway.

Comment: what is your recommend ?

Comment: Using ProGuard to protect something is like leaving his front door unlocked but painting it in the same color as the wall in hope no one will notice this door. ProGuard can't protect your username or your password. It just can try to hide it, but this won't help much.

Comment: i got nothing now..i'm very confused ,what should i do ?

Comment: Once I have reverse engineering the apk I am not able to get function code so you can try create one function which return your password and create apk with proGuard and try to reverse engineering and check whether you are able to get password??

Comment: are you certainly sure ? In my opion,i checked some issue about this and research how to crypt to ID,Password..etc.,Every SHA or MD system return dex code from method.Maybe you are right about this, like i said i'm very very new in android , and i don't want to give someone my ftp's address but thank you your comment

Comment: hey @massaimara98 can you fetch password from server ? when you are try to log in just before requesting for login you can get password from server in encrypted mod . your password have some padding and also encrypted as you know padding and decryption technique so you get plain text at run time

Comment: @andruboy can you explain more? , sorry but i dont get it very much .. :(

Comment: ya sure, don't store your password locally get it from server that password with padding and encrypted Ex. your password is `mass123!@#` now add some padding like  `padmasspad123!@#pad` now encrypt this password on server with MD5 and  get it from server do reverse of this so you can get your pwd in plain text got it ??

Answer (score 0):

Beyond ProGuard, there are other obfuscation technologies that can be used to protect your Android apps. For example, the same author of ProGuard has created an Android-specific version called **DexGuard** that has more advanced features such as string encryption.

No single technique is enough to thwart a determined attacker. Security is a process, not a one-click solution. However, the amount of protection gained by simply enabling ProGuard is worth consideration by all Android developers.

Comment: i'm very new in android platform i dont know some things,i checked has it price right ?

Comment: Yes, It starts with 480 €, per developer per year.